# Pandas - split one row value and merge with multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframes like as below

```
proj_df = pd.DataFrame({'reg_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                              'partner': ['ABC_123','ABC_123','ABC_123','ABC_123','ABC_123','ABC_123','ABC_123'],
                              'part_no':['P123','P123','P123','P123','P123','P123','P123'],
                              'cust_info':['Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple','Tesla'],
                              'qty_1st_year':[100,100,600,150,50,0,10]})

order_df = pd.DataFrame({'partner': ['ABC_123','ABC_123','JKL_123','MNO_123'],
                         'part_no':['P123','P123','Q123','P567'],
                         'cust_info':['Apple','Hyundai','REON','Renault'],
                         'order_qty':[1000,600,50,0]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Merge two dataframes based on `partner,part_no,cust_info`

b) split the `order_qty` column from `order_df` and assign the appropriate portion to a new column called `assigned_qty`

c) appropriate portion is determined by the percentage distribution of `qty_1st_year`. Meaning, you divide individual `qty_1st_year` value by the total sum of `Qty_1st_year` for each group of `partner,part_no and cust_info`.

So, I tried the below

```
sum_df = proj_df.groupby(['partner','part_no','cust_info'])['qty_1st_year'].sum().reset_index()
sum_df.columns = ['partner','part_no','cust_info','total_qty_all_project']

t1=proj_df.merge(order_df,on=['partner','part_no','cust_info'],how='left')
t2 = t1.merge(sum_df,on=['partner','part_no','cust_info'],how='left')
t2['pct_value'] = (t2['qty_1st_year']/t2['total_qty_all_project'])*100
proj_df['assigned_value'] = (t2['order_qty']*t2['pct_value'])/100
```

While this seems to work fine, I would like to know is there any other better and elegant way to do this task.

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new column for avoid double merge, last if need remove columns after  multiplication and division add [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), last if necessary divide by `10` for expected ouput:

```
proj_df['total_qty'] = (proj_df.groupby(['partner','part_no','cust_info'])['qty_1st_year']
                               .transform('sum'))

df=proj_df.merge(order_df,on=['partner','part_no','cust_info'],how='left')

df['assigned_value'] = (df.pop('order_qty')*
                       (df['qty_1st_year']/
                       df.pop('total_qty'))).div(10)
print (df)
   reg_id  partner part_no cust_info  qty_1st_year  assigned_value
0       1  ABC_123    P123     Apple           100            10.0
1       2  ABC_123    P123     Apple           100            10.0
2       3  ABC_123    P123     Apple           600            60.0
3       4  ABC_123    P123     Apple           150            15.0
4       5  ABC_123    P123     Apple            50             5.0
5       6  ABC_123    P123     Apple             0             0.0
6       7  ABC_123    P123     Tesla            10             NaN
```